# Are the fish in the last area of Hades unobtainable after the credits?

Tags: hades

The last part of the game changes after your reach the credits:

> You stop getting to Persephone's farm and just get a cutscene before being thrown back to the house of Hades.
>  But on the way to the farm, after the run completes, there are 2 lakes where you can fish.

Question is: If you do not get all the fishes that are available in those 2 lakes before the credits roll, are you then stuck that on that savefile, you will never be able to get those?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fish in those lakes are the same as the ones that can appear in the final Boss room as that's considered part of the Greece zone.

I've been able to get all 3 of the Greece fish from that room.

Comment: Ah I guess I was unlucky to get a fish spawn in that room but yeah, theres that lake behind hades that could be a spawn point.

Comment: There's also some water down to the bottom right.  The spawn rate in that room is rather high, I see it maybe every 4 runs?  You might've been unlucky.

Comment: Or maybe when I just were in a battle to the death with my dad i'm not really in a mood to check the room. :p

Comment: @Fredy31 just listen for the audio cue. Though I still miss that one at times, but that's the easiest way to tell if there are fishing spots.

Comment: Yeah I know. Really I try to listen to that ding. I get like 1 or 2 fishes by run, are you getting way more and I'm just not paying attention?

Comment: Fishing points have quite a bit of RNG for spawning, After each one there's also a "cooldown" where another one cannot spawn until a certain number of rooms have been cleared which varies per region. I'll usually finish a run with 2-3 fish but that number can vary up or down a fair bit due to variance

Comment: The cooldown for that room is quite low on purpose as it becomes the only way to get certain fish past a point in the game.  See here for more info: https://hades.gamepedia.com/Fishing.  @Fredy31 I usually get extra motivation to beat the boss if I notice a fishing spot before the fight :)